What do I need to communicate about metallic ink printing to a print shop?
Suppose I have some vector shapes or even a complex composition in a AI file format. For portions of this I would like to use metallic inks to give it some flair.
For the moment, I have just colored these sections with a gold hexcode as a placeholder. Though it has now dawned on me that I don't actually know how I will need to communicate with my software that renders my image or the firm/hardware of the printers that will ultimately print out my art.
For context, it won't all be metallic, just certain portions of the images.
According to this post: Gold Metallic Pantone Colour for Print
, I should just design as normal and communicate to the print shop that I want to use metallic ink.
In my application, there will be many different images, all with different amounts of gold. In some cases there are areas I want to be gold metallic and others to be plain gold.
Question
Must I explain to the print shop or supply them with the exact hexcode or pantone that I want to be printed in metallic form? My concern is that if it's very time consuming and difficult for the print shop it will be expensive for me; perhaps there is a standardized way of handling these types of orders?
[Aiming for an end form factor of a binded portfolio/book]

you should definitely check with the printer to be sure they even support customers sending files with spot colors (i.e. not just CMYK or RGB).

This would be a classical "expectations vs reality".
There is no "Normal"
On that post, you can see that if you send the file to be printed with 1 metallic ink you will have a dull, flat result that will have some glare at some angles, but that is it.
A file to be printed on 1 spot ink is just a grayscale image. But specifically a gold ink needs to be highly contrasted. A.
You probably have a decent look on a less contrasted file B.
But you can not have a normal grayscale file C. You can but it will look weird.

In the end, metallic ink is just 1 colored ink, and in some conditions when you have a light behind you, you can see a glare. D but if your image has some gradients because it is not fully contrasted, the gradients can be confusing vs the "glare" E.

It can be a flat image or maybe experiment with some gradients.

But you still can do interesting stuff. But you need to clearly define what is what ink, indicating it as a spot ink on your file.

You could extract some specific zones on rare occasions, playing with masks.
But the file should be quite specific. You will get collage-like results, not shiny glossy results.


Your specific question.

perhaps there is a standardized way of handling these types of orders?

No one will take the idea from your brain and translate it into a finished product without cost.
A printer normally does one thing. Print. And they will print what you have. If you do not have it it needs to be done. So you then need a designer to translate your vision into a finished design that is feasible to be printed.
https://www.pexels.com/es-es/foto/mujer-modelo-maqueta-retrato-20439300/
https://www.pexels.com/es-es/foto/mujer-en-pie-de-pie-sonriente-16820034/
